# Issue setting and redirecting user if cookie is null jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cookies

In my home page I have the following script, when the user comes to our site we check for two things

1. if the screen size is less then 800 if so we redirect them to the mobile site
2. If they have come from the mobile site as they have the option to "View Full Site" from the footer located on the mobile site then we need to create a cookie to allow for the individual to browse the site without any interruptions.

Now with the below code we have some issues. which are as followed when we do

```
var value = getCookie('example');
```

value is always underfined which I would expect if they browse directly to the site for the first time and the previous url isn't the mobile site.

But If I go direct to the main site and get directed to the mobile and press "View Full Site" the below script will run but the cookie is never created so when I click on one of the menu items on the main site and the browse back to the home page i'm redirected to the mobile site because the value of the cookie is underfined? so the question is what am I doing wrong here?

to clarify if the cookie is null redirect them to the mobile site, if its not null do no redirect them allow them to browse the main site.

```
var oldURL = document.referrer;

    var value = getCookie('example');

    alert(oldURL);
    alert(value); // Always undefined? 

    // If this is true they have come from the mobile site
    if (oldURL.indexOf("m.domain") > -1) {

        if (value == null) {
            var date = new Date();
            var minutes = 30;
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
            $.cookie("example", "Yes", { expires: date });
        }

    }
    else { // Otherwise if the screen width is small then 800px wide re-direct them to the mobile site

        if (value == null) { // If value is null that means they have come to the main site so re-direct them to the mobile version
            if (screen.width <= 800) {
                window.location = "m.domain.com";
            }
        }
    }

    function getCookie(c_name) {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to get it to work with the below.

```
 var oldURL = document.referrer;

    var t = getCookie("fromMobile");

    if (oldURL.indexOf("m.domain") > -1) {
        var date = new Date();
        var minutes = 30;
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = "fromMobile=Yes; expires="+ date.toGMTString() +"; path=/";
    } else {
        if (t == "") {
            if (screen.width <= 800) {
                window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
            }
        }
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
```